# Opening Port 18080 for Incoming Connections on Router

Tags: monerod, daemon, full-node, nodes, ports

How do I make port `18080` open for incoming connections on my router on Linux (*Ubuntu 16.04*) for running the Monero daemon?

I don't have access to the physical router in my building that I use for wireless connection to the Internet and I am wondering if I can do so using **Ubuntu 16.04**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods to open ports are specific to the router you have. You don't need physical access to the router, just access to the routers web admin interface. So, I suggest you search for your specific router model and instructions, if this is your own router.

If you are on a non-configurable network like a public WiFi, instead you need to ask the Internet provider to open the port for you.

If you need to configure the Ubuntu firewall, you can install `iptables` plus `ufw` and open the `18080` port on the firewall with the directive `ufw allow`.

Answer (score 0):

As @jtgrassie already mentioned, `ufw` is one of the tools that allows you to manage your ports.
It is convenient to use `ufw` in a script, in conjunction with a **cronjob**, that automates the opening and closing of the port. I find such script particularly useful when I may want to temporarily stop my `monerod` for the sake of freeing my computer's resources (CPU/RAM/bandwith). And so the following script opens and closes port 18080 for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/pgrep -f /home/jerzy/monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.2.0/monerod
#The following ifs deal with monerod when it is running.
if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]; then

 /usr/sbin/ufw allow 18080 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
 
else

 /usr/sbin/ufw deny 18080 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
 
fi
```

Please remember to replace `/home/jerzy/monero-x86_64-linux-gnu-v0.17.2.0/` with the path to `monerod` on your computer.
Once you've made your script executable with `sudo chmod 755 name_of_the_script.sh` than proceed to schedule its execution by cron:
`sudo crontab -e` and appending the following line:

```
* * * * * /path_to_the_script.sh
```